# Regarding Archimedes Principle of Buoyancy

Tags: fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

Am of the opinion - "Archimedes principle of Buoyancy" the statement that the total Buoyant force is equal to the weight of the volume of fluid displaced by the submerged object is not accurate. Because the volume displaced depends on the relative size of the object and the container having the fluid. However the buoyant force depends on gravity head(ρ g h ) and the area of the bottom surface of the object. This also has implication on the net work done in pushing the object against the buoyant force into lighter fluid..

To support this argument am including an experimental setup wherein the volume of water is quite less than(20%) the volume of object being submerged and by virtue of gravity head(ρgh) the net buoyant force is still 1Kg.wt(9.8N) corresponding to 1000cc of the bottle volume. Please refer to the attached image. Thanks for reading...[image]

Comment: "buoyant force is equal to the volume of the fluid displaced". It's equal to the weight of the volume of fluid displaced.

Comment: "Because the volume displaced depends on the relative size of the object and the container having the fluid" . Can you elaborated on why the volume depends on this? Not clear to me what you are saying.

Comment: The volume displaced does NOT depend on the size of the fluid container, an object displaces the same amount whether it is in a bucket of water or in a lake.

Comment: Bravo. Thanks for your Painstaking explanation.

Comment: Still I would want to support my view please refer to the picture depictimng my experimental setup...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way to compute the buoyant force is simply to compute the net force due to the pressure acting on the boundary of the object.  Recognizing that the pressure has a gradient along the direction of gravity, $p = p_0 - \rho g z$, (where $\rho$ is the density of the fluid the object is submerged in) then allows you to convert the surface integral into a volume integral, which results in the weight of the fluid being displaced.
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{F}&=\int_S -p\ \mathbf{n}\ dS \\
&=\int_S -(p_0-\rho gz)\ \mathbf{n}\ dS \\
&=\int_V -\mathbf{\nabla}(p_0-\rho gz)\ dV = \rho gV\mathbf{e}_z
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that does not require any calculus is to simply analyze a free body diagram of the object along with a prismatic region of fluid (height $H$ and cross-sectional area $A$) surrounding the submerged object.  Envision the object being held in place by a string and let's assume that the object wants to float.  Then, the force in the string will be the buoyant force minus the weight of the submerged object. The sum of the forces acting on the system in the direction of gravity is then easy to compute.
[image: Free body diagram of submerged object with surrounding fliud]

$\sum F_z = (p_0+\rho g H)A-p_0 A - F - \rho g (H A - V) - W = 0$

where the first two terms are the forces due to the pressure on the bottom and top of the region, $\rho g (H A - V)$ is the total weight of the fluid, and $W$ is the weight of the object. Then, the simple solution leads to:

$F = \rho g V - W$

where $\rho g V$ is the weight of the fluid displaced by the object, which is the buoyant force. The result is entirely independent of the relative size of the container.